# Remove slugs and redirect using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

Using .htaccess, how can I strip parameters from a url and redirect an entire folder to another location?

For example, I have `http://www.webbiscuit.co.uk/News.aspx/11/favicon-competition` and I just want to redirect this to `http://www.webbiscuit.co.uk/`.

I have tried

```
Redirect 301 /News.aspx http://www.webbiscuit.co.uk/
```

but that just strips off the `News.aspx` part, and redirects me to

```
http://www.webbiscuit.co.uk/11/favicon-competition
```

How can I strip off the entire file and the slugs?

Comment: Are you OK to use mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) .. or you want `Redirect` directive only?

Comment: I think a RewriteRule might be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Using mod_rewrite (the `?` may be unnecessary here):

```
RewriteRule ^News\.aspx(.*) http://www.webbiscuit.co.uk/? [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: I can't do it for any url.  I need to redirect within the same domain, and only if it begins with "http://www.webbiscuit.co.uk/News.aspx"

Comment: So ... you want redirect (301) ONLY for News.apsx? If so -- I'm updating my answer in a moment.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not being clear.  Thank you for your help, but unfortunately that does not seem to strip off the folders that come after News.aspx, it just pulls out the News.aspx part.

Comment: Try another browser or clear your browser caches and restart -- modern browsers DO CACHE redirects. I tested and it works fine for me.

Comment: I do not know then -- it's a basic simple rule... How much control so you have over your Apache? Can you edit config files (httpd-vhost.conf)? If yes -- you can enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`) and see where and why it redirects this way.